# Wordpress error "Could not insert attachment into the database" when uploading files

Tags: wordpress, upload

After working on the website without issue for the afternoon, I am suddenly presented with a "Could not insert attachment into the database." error any time I try to upload any files. The size and type of file does not seem to matter.

I have checked permissions and the file upload size and memory limits in WordPress and don't see an issue there. No changes were made between the last successful upload and uploads failing (only a matter of minutes).

I have found that the files are uploading correctly to the file system but are not available within WordPress.

Comment: Hey Kenn, did you ever figure this out by chance?

Comment: I did solve this. I found some errors in the MySQL database that were introduced by a plugin. I was able to correct them manually and everything works fine now.

Comment: Thanks Kenn! That was my issue too!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a MySQL database issue. To find the exact error that's preventing you from uploading media, you can turn on wordpress debug logging by adding `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` to your `wp-config.php` file, then re-create the error, and find the full error message in the `debug.log` file inside `wp-content` folder (more detailed instructions can be found [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-set-up-wordpress-error-logs-in-wp-config/)).

In my case, the error was a duplicated primary key when trying to insert into the `mac_posts` table. The images were actually uploading to the `wp-content/uploads` folder on the server just fine, but wordpress makes an entry in the `mac_posts` table for every media item uploaded so it can display it in the wordpress media library. Looking in the database table using phpMyAdmin, the row with the existing ID was a wpforms contact form, so I just deleted that row from the table, re-created the contact form manually, and that fixed the table and the upload issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error, figured out it was the length of the image name. Fixed it by renaming to shorter name.